# Fog seems not very obvious, how to adjust parameters?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d

I wanna create some fog effect but have some troubles. Basically, my scene has a point light and a solid sphere with black background. I created fog however it looks like not very obvious and cannot blend into the background.

Here is my render code:

```
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1); //black background.
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, fLowLight);//fLowLight=(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f, 1.0f )
    glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER, GL_FALSE);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_AMBIENT, m_fIa);//m_fIa = (0.5,0.5,0.5)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_DIFFUSE, m_fId); //m_fId = (0.5,0.5,0.5)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_SPECULAR, m_fIs);//m_fIs = (0.5,0.5,0.5)


    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT2);

    glMateriali(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 128);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, m_fKs);//m_fKs =(0.5,0.5,0.5)
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, m_fKa);//m_fKa = (0.5,0.5,0.5)
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, m_fKd);//m_fKd = (0.5,0.5,0.5)
    //glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);

    glFogi(GL_FOG_MODE, GL_LINEAR);
    glFogfv(GL_FOG_COLOR, fogColor);//fogColor = (0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glFogf(GL_FOG_DENSITY, 0.8f);
    glHint(GL_FOG_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glFogf(GL_FOG_START, 1.0f);
    glFogf(GL_FOG_END, 100.0f);
    if(m_bFog)
        glEnable(GL_FOG);


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60, 1, 1, 4000);

    gluLookAt(0.0f, 50.0f , 50.0f ,0.0f, 0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f , 0.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glLoadIdentity();


    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_POSITION, fLightPos2);//fLightPos2 = (0, 50, 20)

    glColor3f(0.4,0.4,0.4);
    glutSolidSphere(20, 32, 32);

    glDisable(GL_FOG);
    glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHT2);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glFlush();
```

Here is the screenshot without fog:
[image: No fog]
Here is the screenshoy WITH fog:
[image]

I think there must be something wrong because the fog is so thin even though I set the GL_FOG_DENSITY to 0.8. Maybe there are some parameters need to change. Any suggestions?

Also, I wanna the fog can be everywhere in the scene, I mean, red fog can blend into the black background not only exists around the sphere, how to do this?

Could anyone give me some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand how fixed-function fog works to understand why the black background is not being "fogged". This is something applied after rasterization, when it comes time to shade polygons fog is applied to the polygons as a function of your color, density (exp/exp<sup>2</sup>) start/end (linear) and above all Z distance.

The thing is, your black background is ***not*** a polygon. You cleared the color buffer to black, so shading and thus fog, is never applied to it.

> ## Name
>
> > **[glFog](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFog.xml)** — specify fog parameters
> >
> > [...]
> >
> > > While enabled, fog affects rasterized geometry, bitmaps, and pixel blocks, ***but not buffer clear operations***.

---

### You have two options to rectify this:

#### Smart way:

- Acknowledge that the background is at a constant distance from the camera, and change your cleared background color accordingly.

#### Naive way:

- Draw a black quad in NDC-space at Z=**1.0** (far clip plane) with Z-fog enabled.

If you understand the various [equations GL uses for fog](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFog.xml) adequately, you can compute a constant clear color for the background. However, if you do not want to be bothered with this the second approach will be simpler.

Comment: That explained a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @TonyLic: I should also point out that setting fog density in this example will do nothing, because you are using a linear fog mode. You would need exp or exp^2 for density to do anything.